# MFA Mobile number field restriction

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We want to apply number digit validation while entering mobile number at the time of MFA registration.
We tried to use restriction and predicates, but both doesn't help at all.

Comment: Did you try a regex?

Comment: What technical profile are you using for MFA?

Comment: <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-EditAndVerify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
            <Item Key="language.countryList"><![CDATA[{}]]></Item>

Comment: </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
<InputClaims>
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId">
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />

Comment: Yes, tried regex but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

this example shows to allow users to enter Denmark number with country code or without country code. I am using the regex expression for this validation.

```
  <ClaimType Id="mobile">
        <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Your phone number.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^((\(?\+45\)?)?)(\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2})$" HelpText="Please enter valid phone number e.g +45XXXXXXXX" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
```

but if you want your user only to enter digits with no special character and no alphabet then please follow this

```
 <ClaimType Id="mobile">
        <DisplayName>Phone Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Your phone number.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
         <Pattern RegularExpression="^[0-9]+$" HelpText="Please enter valid phonenumber" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
```